# Hide loader after script and images are loaded Completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am included external script and lib. and images are in DOM. I want to remove loader after images and scripts are loaded completely in URL.

```
window.onload= function(){
    $(".loader").hide();
}
```

but it is not working before script or image loaded it is executed.

Comment: Please provide as much information as you can so we can help you.

Comment: There's no inherent way to determine if a *script* has loaded.  Some scripts (eg google maps) provide a callback mechanism and some script loader wrappers provide this, so it will depend on how and what you are loading for script - which you've not detailed.   For images and DOM in general, use `$(function() { [code] }` which is the jquery shorthand for document ready.

Comment: okay means we dont have such thing to know whether out script is loaded or not

Answer (score 2):

you syntax is incorrect. use this

replace

```
window.onload= function(){
```

by

```
$(window).load(function() {})
```

the  `$(window).load()` function run when the page is fully loaded including graphics. see https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: is it run after scripts are loaded

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the image is loaded using a `setTimeout`, take a look below:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        //Check if the image or whatever is loaded  
    }, 30000);
```

Also you can create an attribute to don't enter again in the setTimeout after your stuffs are loaded, like:

var isLoaded = 0;

```
if(isLoaded == 0){
        setTimeout(function () {
             isLoaded  = 1;
            //Check if the image or whatever is loaded  
        }, 30000);
}
```

You can encapsulate your code in different cases:

- The code below it'll wait for all the images and text assets to finish loading before executing.

  $(window).load(function(){
     //your code
  });
- The code below it'll wait for the text assets to be loaded

  $(document).ready(function(){
     //your code
  });

I hope it's helps.

Comment: `$(window).load(function(){});`, as far as I know, wait for **all** of the window requests (including iframes) are done to trigger anything that it's inside of it. Anyone, correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: @ghaschel you are right, I have added an extra information because I miss information in the question.

Comment: what about script. how should I check that script is loaded completely

Comment: It also waits for scripts and stylesheets. :)